# TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file after upgrading to 6.2.26

Tags: php, tcpdf

I upgraded to php 7.2.9 and I tried to upgrade TCPDF to 6.2.26
I did the last update by copying all the files on top, and I tried a new directory TCPDF.

The problem I have:
When I use

```
$pdf->Output("/tmp/xx.pdf", 'I');
```

I get the error in the title. When I use 'F' it works fine.

A workaround is using: 
ob_start();
...
ob_end_flush();

My questions:

1. did I update TCPDF correctly?
2. how can I see which error is send to output
3. how to solve this issue in a clean way

Thanks for any help

Comment: _did I update TCPDF correctly?_ Answer: How could we possibly know?

Comment: Q2) We would need to see all the code to work out where you send something to the browser before doing the pdf output

Comment: Oh and we prefer one question per question

Comment: no output before the call to `$pdf->Output` if your sending it as a stream. what your output is, only you can work out

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  To clarify my first question. I unzipped the tcpdf_6_2_26.zip file into an empty TCPDF directory. Is that sufficent to update TCPDF?

Comment: I didn't send anything to the pdf output.  It worked in the past with an older PHP version. If I use $pdf->Output("/tmp/xx.pdf", 'I');   I get an error. If I use $pdf->Output("/tmp/xx.pdf", 'F');  it works fine. This issue was reported before but should have been solved in the 6.2.23 version. If necessary I can produce a small script which has the same issue. However I don´t know how to attach it here.  Just include in the message?